# post array inside json object in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I m working with retrofit  and sending to request to server via post method i am getting response currectly  for this json see this is post i m sending to server .

> adreess class for post i m using this object

```
{
     "years":"1855",
     "months":"6",
     "skills":1
}
```

> now  i have to implement array inside object in skills how to post this

```
{
    "years":"1",
    "months":"6",
    "skills":["1","2","3"],
}
```

how to get array inside object in retrofit 
i m using interface like this

```
Call<AddressResponce> address(@Body Adreess adreess);
```

Comment: json not end with semicolon lion "skills":["1","2","3"], check that also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("years")
@Expose
private String years;
@SerializedName("months")
@Expose
private String months;
@SerializedName("skills")
@Expose
private List<String> skills = null;

public String getYears() {
return years;
}

public void setYears(String years) {
this.years = years;
}

public String getMonths() {
return months;
}

public void setMonths(String months) {
this.months = months;
}

public List<String> getSkills() {
return skills;
}

public void setSkills(List<String> skills) {
this.skills = skills;
}

}
```

I hope it's useful to you ..!

Comment: please upvode if you find intresting in this

Answer (score 4):

Roughly it would look like this:

RequestBody class should have an array to hold that Skills list

```
class RequestBody {
   int years; 
   int months;
   int[] skills;
}

@POST(“url”)
Call<AddressResponce> address(@Body RequestBody requestbody);
```

See if it works.

Comment: hi it is looking like currect but in skill class what i have to send

Comment: means skills like 1 ,,2, 3 ,4 dynamical  it can be  many like array

Comment: what i have to write in skill class to store like that

Comment: If it is simple string or int, you can replace Skill[] with int[] or String[]. no need to create class then.

Comment: suppose i m sending skills[1,2,3]  its int then what i have to write inside  skill class

Comment: @ani plese heelp me i m not geting

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have a look, if it not works, then you must post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```
    @SerializedName("skills")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> skills= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Hit URl in Get Mode

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=ec01f8c2eb6ac402f2ca026dc2d9b8fd&language=en_US&page=1

Source Code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUUy00M2RCSERvMWc

```
 package com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TopRatedMovies {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The page
     */
    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param page
     * The page
     */
    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The results
     */
    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param results
     * The results
     */
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The totalResults
     */
    public Integer getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param totalResults
     * The total_results
     */
    public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The totalPages
     */
    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param totalPages
     * The total_pages
     */
    public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

}



package com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Result {

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;

    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private Double voteAverage;

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }
    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public Boolean getAdult() {
        return adult;
    }
    public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }
    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }
    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }
    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }
    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }
    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }
    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }
    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }
    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }
    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }
    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }
    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }
    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }
}





package com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.adapters.RetrofitArrayInsideArrayAdapter;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.api.MovieApi;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.api.MovieService;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.models.Result;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.models.TopRatedMovies;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.utils.PaginationScrollListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivityArrayInsideArray extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private static final String TAG = "ArrayInsideArray";

    RetrofitArrayInsideArrayAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    LinearLayout errorLayout;
    Button btnRetry;
    TextView txtError;

    private static final int PAGE_START = 1;  // TODO Important Role Here
//    private static final int PAGE_START = 2;  // TODO Important Role Here
//    private static final int PAGE_START = 3;  // TODO Important Role Here
//    private static final int PAGE_START = 4;  // TODO Important Role Here
//    private static final int PAGE_START = 5;  // TODO Important Role Here


    private int currentPage = PAGE_START;

    private MovieService movieService;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.main_progress);
        errorLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.error_layout);
        btnRetry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.error_btn_retry);
        txtError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_txt_cause);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Array Inside Array Retrofit 2");

        adapter = new RetrofitArrayInsideArrayAdapter(this);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //init service and load data
        movieService = MovieApi.getClient().create(MovieService.class);

        loadFirstPage();

        btnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadFirstPage();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    private void loadFirstPage() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadFirstPage: ");

        // To ensure list is visible when retry button in error view is clicked
        hideErrorView();

        callTopRatedMoviesApi().enqueue(new Callback<TopRatedMovies>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TopRatedMovies> call, Response<TopRatedMovies> response) {
                // Got data. Send it to adapter

                hideErrorView();

                List<Result> results = fetchResults(response);


                for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++) {
                    Log.e("keshav", "Title ->" + results.get(i).getTitle());
                    Log.e("keshav", "Id ->" + results.get(i).getGenreIds());

                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapter.addAll(results);
//                if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
//                else isLastPage = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TopRatedMovies> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                showErrorView(t);
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Result> fetchResults(Response<TopRatedMovies> response) {
        TopRatedMovies topRatedMovies = response.body();
        return topRatedMovies.getResults();
    }

    private Call<TopRatedMovies> callTopRatedMoviesApi() {

        return movieService.getTopRatedMovies(
                getString(R.string.my_api_key),
                "en_US",
                currentPage
        );
    }


    private void showErrorView(Throwable throwable) {

        if (errorLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            txtError.setText(fetchErrorMessage(throwable));
        }
    }

    private String fetchErrorMessage(Throwable throwable) {
        String errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);

        if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
            errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_no_internet);
        } else if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
            errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_timeout);
        }

        return errorMsg;
    }

    // Helpers -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    private void hideErrorView() {
        if (errorLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
}


package com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.R;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.models.Result;
import com.keshav.retroft2arrayinsidearrayexamplekeshav.utils.PaginationAdapterCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RetrofitArrayInsideArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    // View Types
    private static final int ITEM = 0;
    private static final String BASE_URL_IMG = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w150";


    private List<Result> movieResults;
    private Context context;

    private boolean retryPageLoad = false;
    private String errorMsg;

    public RetrofitArrayInsideArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        movieResults = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());


        Log.e("keshav", "onCreateViewHolder Adapter ->" + viewType);

        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM:
                View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_new, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new MovieVH(viewItem);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Result result = movieResults.get(position); // Movie

        Log.e("keshav", "onBindViewHolder ->" + getItemViewType(position));
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

            case ITEM:
                final MovieVH movieVH = (MovieVH) holder;
//                movieVH.mMovieTitle.setText(result.getTitle());
//                movieVH.mMovieTitle.setText("Keshav "+result.getGenreIds());
                movieVH.mMovieTitle.setText(result.getTitle() + " " + result.getGenreIds());
                movieVH.mYear.setText(formatYearLabel(result));
                movieVH.mMovieDesc.setText(result.getOverview());
                movieVH.tv_vote_count.setText("Vote Count :- " + result.getVoteCount());
                movieVH.tv_id.setText("ID :- " + result.getId());
                movieVH.tv_video.setText("Video :- " + result.getVideo());
                movieVH.tv_vote_average.setText("Vote Average :- " + result.getVoteAverage());
                movieVH.tv_popularity.setText("Popularity :- " + result.getPopularity());

                // load movie thumbnail
                loadImage(result.getPosterPath())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                // TODO: 08/11/16 handle failure
//                                movieVH.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                // image ready, hide progress now
//                                movieVH.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;   // return false if you want Glide to handle everything else.
                            }
                        })
                        .into(movieVH.mPosterImg);
                // load movie thumbnail
                loadImage(result.getBackdropPath())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                // TODO: 08/11/16 handle failure
                                movieVH.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                // image ready, hide progress now
                                movieVH.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;   // return false if you want Glide to handle everything else.
                            }
                        })
                        .into(movieVH.iv_backdrop_path);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieResults == null ? 0 : movieResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.e("keshav", "getItemViewType ->" + movieResults.size());
        Log.e("keshav", "getItemView-1 ->" + movieResults.size());
        Log.e("keshav", "getItemView-2 ->" + position);
        return ITEM;
    }

    private String formatYearLabel(Result result) {
        if (result != null && result.getReleaseDate() != null) {
            Log.e("keshav", "formatYearLabel -> " + result.getReleaseDate());
            return result.getReleaseDate().substring(0, 4)  // we want the year only
                    + " | "
                    + result.getOriginalLanguage().toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return "Keshav";
        }
    }


    private DrawableRequestBuilder<String> loadImage(@NonNull String posterPath) {
        return Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(BASE_URL_IMG + posterPath)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)   // cache both original & resized image
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade();
    }


    /*
        Helpers - Pagination
   _________________________________________________________________________________________________
    */

    public void add(Result r) {
        movieResults.add(r);
        notifyItemInserted(movieResults.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addAll(List<Result> moveResults) {
        for (Result result : moveResults) {
            add(result);
        }
    }

    public Result getItem(int position) {
        return movieResults.get(position);
    }

    public void showRetry(boolean show, @Nullable String errorMsg) {
        retryPageLoad = show;
        notifyItemChanged(movieResults.size() - 1);

        if (errorMsg != null) this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    protected class MovieVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mMovieTitle;
        private TextView mMovieDesc;
        private TextView mYear; // displays "year | language"
        private TextView tv_vote_count;
        private TextView tv_id;
        private TextView tv_video;
        private TextView tv_vote_average;
        private TextView tv_popularity;
        private ImageView mPosterImg;
        private ImageView iv_backdrop_path;
        private ProgressBar mProgress;

        public MovieVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mMovieTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
            mMovieDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_desc);
            tv_vote_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vote_count);
            tv_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            tv_video = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video);
            tv_vote_average = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vote_average);
            tv_popularity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_popularity);
            mYear = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_year);
            mPosterImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
            iv_backdrop_path = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_backdrop_path);
            mProgress = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_progress);
        }
    }
}
```